# How to access the FirstData web service integration WSDL file?

Tags: curl, apache-axis, ssl-certificate, keystore, pem

FirstData has horrendous customer support, but I have to integrate with their Global Gateway web service for a project I'm working on. I'm simply trying to run the Axis2 wsdl2java tool according to the instructions in [their manual](http://www.firstdata.com/downloads/marketing-merchant/fdgg-web-service-api-v1-1.pdf).

This basically consists of adding the **keyStore** and **keyStorePassword** JVM parameter. I've done both, but I continue to get *Connection reset* errors when trying to run:

```
wsdl2java.bat -uri https://www.staging.linkpointcentral.com/fdggwsapi/order.wsdl -S C:\
```

When I try to access the URL with my browser, I get

> Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET): Unknown error.

I assume there are developers out there who have completed a FirstData web service integration. What am I doing wrong?

I've also tried connecting via cURL:

```
C:\curl-7.19.7-ssl-sspi-zlib-static-bin-w32>curl --cert C:\FDGGWS\WSXXXXXXXXXX._.1.pem --key C:\FDGGWS\WSXXXXXXXXXX._.1.key --insecure  https://www.staging.linkpointcentral.com/fdggwsapi/order.wsdl
Enter PEM pass phrase:
curl: (52) SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 10054
```

I know I'm entering the correct key password because when I enter a fake one I get:

> curl: (58) unable to set private key file: 'C:\FDGGWS\WSXXXXXXXXXX._.1.key' type PEM

Comment: Hi. I am facing the same problem, but I am using .NET. I tried installing the client certificate to browse the WSDL, but I am unable to reach the site itself. Did you get any success?

Comment: @Kirtan - no, and I tried everything. Mostly I couldn't get through to their tech support (listed at Level 1 in the guide) and when I did they weren't helpful. I tried using a browser (with cert installed) to get the WSDL, cURL, Axis/JVM, and none of them work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please correct the wsdl url to https://www.staging.linkpointcentral.com/fdggwsapi/services/order.wsdl and try generating the stub classes. I tried in browser and i am able to generate java stubs.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it looks like you were pointing to the wrong URL.  Also, http://www.robinsontechnical.com has information on First Data Web Services too.

Answer (score 0):

https://ws.merchanttest.firstdataglobalgateway.com/fdggwsapi/services/order.wsdl

This seems to be the correct URL for the test environment.